# Using one visa-free to enter Vietnam to avoid multiple-entry visa

Tags: visas, france, vietnam, french-citizens

I have a French passport which allows one visa-free entry to Vietnam for 15 days
[Vietnam visa exemption](https://vietnamembassy-thailand.org/which-countries-are-exempt-from-vietnam-visa/)

My trip to Vietnam will include a less-than-15-day trip 13-Jan-2020 to 26-Jan-2020, then I leave for Malaysia for a couple of days 26-Jan to 30-Jan and back to Vietnam for a week 30-Jan to 5-Feb before flying out.

Can I use the visa-free permission to enter the first part, then another single-entry e-visa to return the second time ? I wouldn't prefer multiple entry because it cannot be done on line, and the visa-on-arrival line at the airport is ridiculously long. Single-entry e visa also costs less.

Another related question is : Can you apply for 2 single-entry e-visa with overlapping validity to replace a multiple-entry visa ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use your visa free entry the first time and your visa for the second visit, I have done this numerous times being a Swedish passport holder we can enter once every 30 days visa free and if more I apply for a visa for the second visit.

No you cannot have two over lapping visas single entry as soon as your second visa becomes active your previous visa is void and cannot be used

Comment: Great answer. About overlapping visas. Let's say the trip is 1,5 month. Can you use 2 single-entry visas while staying inside the country the whole time ? First one let's say Jan-1 to Jan-30, second one Feb-1 to Mar-1. Coming into the country by the first visa, out by the second visa.

Comment: @Kenny no this is not possible, at entry the immigrations officer will only look at 1 visa and write your exit date based on that

Comment: Just adding to this as I passed vietnam immigrations in HCM yesterday and confirmed this, the officer will only look at one visa and based on that make his decisions

Answer (score 1):

Please check the explanations on this site [vietnamsvisa](https://www.vietnamsvisa.com/single-entry-visas/). If you choose a single-entry visa, you are allowed to enter/leave Vietnam only once in the allocated period, after which you have to apply for a new visa.

So to answer your question: Yes, you could apply for 2 single-entry visas for your purposed trip. I don't know anything about the second question but from a legal point of view you probably can't get 2 overlapping visas (to somehow "cheat" the system).

Comment: 1/ The website cannot be reached. Also it seems like one of the fake website. There have been a lot of notice. Only the by the Embassy of the Immigration department with .gov are authentic. 2/ There is contradiction in your answer : If I apply for 2 single-entry visas, they are inevitably overlapping. A single-entry visa is valid for 1 month. That means the first one will cover 13-Jan to 13-Feb, the second one 30-Jan to 28-Feb. They are already overlapping.

Comment: @Kenny I was refering that you probably can't get multiple single entry visas so you can prolong your stay without leaving, but I read your last question a bit wrong. On the other hand. I also found this article on Vietnam visa on [Trip Advisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293924-i8595-k11165770-Vietnam_visa_re_entry_policy-Hanoi.html)